# Платформы для C

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Я через визуал студио начал изучать C (win 32), а это для 32 битных компов, но  меня дома 64 бита, это большая проблема и что нужно делать?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для изучения С лучше выбрать что-нибудь попроще, чем VS. Попробуйте IDE Dev-Cpp. Достаточно простая, но функциональная. Использует gcc. Совершенно бесплатная.

А может быть, лучше вообще для начала использовать блокнот и консоль.

Answer (score 0):

С-код компилируется и в 32-бита, и в 64-бита. Если Вы просто изучаете язык, то не имеет значение, на какой машине установлена Visual Studio: это может быть Windows и 32-х, и 64-х бит. Подробнее по ссылка.

- [Поддержка 64-разрядной среды разработки Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms241066.aspx)
- [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb427430.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, то что есть в Visual Studio это не C, а C++. Возможно, он умеет компилировать C-код, но для этого точно тогда потребуется задание опций компилятора (language = xxxx или вроде того).

Во-вторых, разницы между 32-битным и 64-битным кодом не так много. Нужно просто понимать особенности сборки под различные архитектуры и все будет ОК. Например, отличаются размеры типов. Более того - можно писать один код, который будет работать одинаково и на 32-битной и на 64-битной машине, что с перекомпиляцией, что без.

В третьих, WinAPI и там, и там одинаков. Увы, на голом движке языка далеко не уедешь и поэтому приходится использовать сторонние библиотеки. И при их использовании нужно очень внимательно читать документацию. Но с этим проблем нет, т.к. практически вся необходимая Вам информация есть в MSDN.